# Print Combination in an 2D array in python

Tags: python

I have this array:

```
[[0, 3], [1, 4], [2]]
```

i want to display all possible combinations of the array,for example:

```
0 1 2
3 1 2
0 4 2
3 4 2
```

the row and the columns of this array is not constant.it changes by the input of the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product
l = [[0, 3], [1, 4], [2]]

for prod in product(*l):
    print(prod)
```

Comment: @BhargavRao, i prefer the blue highlighting ;)

Comment: Hey, don't you like blue on grey?

Comment: Lol... BTW, your statements are contradictory *i prefer the blue highlighting* and *I am colour blind* :P

Comment: @BhargavRao, there you go, you should never listen to a guy who is colourblind talking about colour ;)